# Issue with range of seed in Python

Tags: python, numpy, csv, scipy, operating-system

In the following code, I want to pick random integers in the range specified by `start_seed` and `end_seed`. But it's showing an error. How can I resolve this?

```
from scipy.stats import truncnorm
import numpy as np
import os
import csv

Runs = 5
Nodes = 1012
start_seed = 1
end_seed = 1e100
desired_mean = 50.0
desired_variance = 5.0

def function(run):
    parent_folder = str(run + 1)
    os.mkdir(parent_folder)

    

    seed = np.random.randint(start_seed, end_seed + 1)
    np.random.seed(seed)
    # Generate truncated normal random numbers with specified mean and variance
    lower_bound = desired_mean - 2 * np.sqrt(desired_variance)
    upper_bound = desired_mean + 2 * np.sqrt(desired_variance)
    r = (1e-6) * truncnorm.rvs((lower_bound - desired_mean) / np.sqrt(desired_variance), (upper_bound - desired_mean) / np.sqrt(desired_variance), loc=desired_mean, scale=np.sqrt(desired_variance), size=Nodes)
    

    
    
    sort_r = np.sort(r)
    r1 = sort_r[::-1]

    r1 = r1.reshape(1, Nodes)

    r2 = r.copy()
    np.random.shuffle(r2.ravel()[1:])
    r2 = r2.reshape(1, Nodes)

    maximum = r2.max()
    indice1 = np.where(r2 == maximum)
    r2[indice1] = r2[0][0]
    r2[0][0] = maximum
    r2[0][Nodes-1] = maximum

    mean = np.mean(r)
    var = np.var(r)
    std = np.std(r)

    # Calculate the rounded mean and variance for the file name
    rounded_mean = "{:.1f}".format(desired_mean)
    rounded_variance = "{:.1f}".format(desired_variance)

    with open(os.path.join(parent_folder, rf"Inv_Radius_{Nodes}_{rounded_mean}_{rounded_variance}ND.csv"), 'w+') as f:
        np.random.shuffle(r2[0][1:-1])
        inv_r = 1/r2
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerows(inv_r)


for x in range(Runs):
    function(x)
```

The error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File c:\users\debanikb\onedrive - technion\research_technion\python_pnm\surfactant a-d\testing\var_5\normal_6.py:67
    function(x)

  File c:\users\debanikb\onedrive - technion\research_technion\python_pnm\surfactant a-d\testing\var_5\normal_6.py:26 in function
    seed = np.random.randint(start_seed, end_seed + 1)

  File mtrand.pyx:746 in numpy.random.mtrand.RandomState.randint

  File _bounded_integers.pyx:1336 in numpy.random._bounded_integers._rand_int32

ValueError: high is out of bounds for int32
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In line

```
seed = np.random.randint(start_seed, end_seed + 1)
```

you are trying to generate the seed with

```
start_seed = 1
end_seed = 1e100
```

The error message tells you `ValueError: high is out of bounds for int32`.
Your `end_seed = 1e100` is the problem because it is way out of bounds of what the `int32` data type is capable to hold.
The range for the `int32` data type in numpy is -2147483648 to 2147483647.

So the value for `end_seed` must not exceeed 2147483647. Then it should not throw an error anymore.

Comment: What if I want t pick an integer greater than ```2147483647```?

Comment: The `np.random.randint()` function allows a parameter `dtype` which sets the output type of the seed. Maybe with this parameter you can provide values greater than `2147483647` if you set it to e.g. `int64`.